# Remove numbers and parentheses at the beginning of each line in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Basically every line in my text file is formatted like this:

```
1) Baker
2) Photographer
3) Doctor
4) Teacher
5) CEO
```

etc, etc.

Using Notepad++ how do I remove the 1), 2), 3), etc?

Comment: Is this a programming question? If yes, show us the code you tried so far. If not, perhaps try superuser.com.

Comment: Use Excel, import as separate columns, and then save just the 2nd column.

Answer (score 4):

1 ) Press <kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd> for pop window to Replace.
 
2 ) Provide the `^\d+\)` regular expression in **Find what** text field, choose option Regular expression in search mode and make empty in **Replace with** text field.
3 ) Click on Replace all or Replace button.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `^\d+\)` (note the trailing whitespace) and replace text matching this pattern with an empty string.

Step-by-step guide:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to open the Replace dialog.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to focus on the Find text field.
3. Enter `^\d+\)` and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> to switch to the Replace with text field.
4. Press backspace to delete any text that might be in this box.
5. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to switch the search mode to regular expression.
6. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to perform a replace all operation on the document.

Comment: Could you put the NP version in your answer incase I ever get NP and want to use it to find and replace something using regular expressions.

Comment: Regular notepad? AFAIK, it doesn't have regex, so you'd use Powershell or a script to do it.

Comment: Windows NP doesn't have a version, is that what you mean by regular ?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I mean. NP++ is totally different than Windows Notepad. The only common ground is the name. I can't imagine a scenario where you'd need to use Notepad over NP++.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the column selection mode, normally accessed with alt + mouse, or by the edit menu, select the 2 columns, and delete them as any text

Comment: But even with 2 or 3 column selections, it's faster than asking here...

Comment: May be, but it will not work if some lines have 1 digit and some other 2 or 3 digits.